# Unit Testing with Jest for Strapi v4

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, strapi

I am trying to perform unit tests with Jest for the new version of Strapi, v4 which was just released a couple of weeks ago. In accordance with their documentation, the old guide for unit testing no longer runs as expected. I have, however, modified the code to work to a certain extent. Currently I have the following:

`./test/helpers/strapi.js`:

```js
const Strapi = require("@strapi/strapi");

let instance;

async function setupStrapi() {
  if (!instance) {
    /** the following code in copied from `./node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js` */
    await Strapi().load();
    instance = strapi; // strapi is global now
    await instance.server
      .use(instance.server.router.routes()) // populate KOA routes
      .use(instance.server.router.allowedMethods()); // populate KOA methods

    await instance.server.mount();
  }
  return instance;
}

module.exports = {
  setupStrapi
};
```

`./tests/app.test.js`:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { setupStrapi } = require("./helpers/strapi");

beforeAll(async () => {
  await setupStrapi();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  const dbSettings = strapi.config.get("database.connection.connection");

  //close server to release the db-file
  await strapi.server.destroy();

  //DATABASE_FILENAME=.tmp/test.db

  //delete test database after all tests
  if (dbSettings && dbSettings.filename) {
    const tmpDbFile = `${dbSettings.filename}`;

    if (fs.existsSync(tmpDbFile)) {
      fs.unlinkSync(tmpDbFile);
    }
  }
});

it("should return hello world", async () => {
  await request(strapi.server.httpServer).get("/api/hello").expect(200); // Expect response http code 200
});
```

`./config/env/test/database.js`

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: "sqlite",
    connection: {
      filename: path.join(
        __dirname,
        "../../../",
        env("DATABASE_FILENAME", ".tmp/test.db")
      ),
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true,
  },
});
```

The route `/api/hello` is a custom API endpoint. This works perfectly when running `strapi develop`, and all permissions are set correctly.

The tests run, but every endpoint that is not `/` or `/admin` returns `403 Forbidden`, meaning there is a problem with the permissions. It would seem that the database file `.tmp/data.db` (used in development) is not replicated correctly in `.tmp/test.db`. In other words, this is close to working, but the permissions for API endpoints are not set correctly.

I have been searching through StackOverflow and the Stapi Forums over the past few days but to no avail. I would greatly appreciate some pointers as to how to fix this :)

Answer (score 2):

So in order for that to work in **v4**, this is how I did.

This was based in [this](https://forum.strapi.io/t/unit-testing-with-jest-for-strapi-v4/15343) and [this](https://forum.strapi.io/t/v4-unit-testing/14818) but Stf's posting in [this](https://forum.strapi.io/t/unit-testing-with-jest-for-strapi-v4/15343) saying "inject them in your database during the bootstrap phase like it is made in the templates" was what really set me in the right track.

So if you look [here](https://github.com/strapi/starters-and-templates/blob/main/packages/templates/blog/template/src/bootstrap.js#L174-L180) you will see this function:

```js
async function setPublicPermissions(newPermissions) {
  // Find the ID of the public role
  const publicRole = await strapi
    .query("plugin::users-permissions.role")
    .findOne({
      where: {
        type: "public",
      },
    });

  // Create the new permissions and link them to the public role
  const allPermissionsToCreate = [];
  Object.keys(newPermissions).map((controller) => {
    const actions = newPermissions[controller];
    const permissionsToCreate = actions.map((action) => {
      return strapi.query("plugin::users-permissions.permission").create({
        data: {
          action: `api::${controller}.${controller}.${action}`,
          role: publicRole.id,
        },
      });
    });
    allPermissionsToCreate.push(...permissionsToCreate);
  });
  await Promise.all(allPermissionsToCreate);
}
```

Later on the code, this function is called like this:

```js
  await setPublicPermissions({
    article: ["find", "findOne"],
    category: ["find", "findOne"],
    author: ["find", "findOne"],
    global: ["find", "findOne"],
    about: ["find", "findOne"],
  });
```

So in my case I modified this function a bit to accept between `authenticated` (`1`) and `public` (`2`) roles inspired by [Sidney C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6281250/sydney-c) answer above.

This is how I did it:

```js
const grantPrivilege = async (roleID = 1, newPermissions) => {
  const roleName = roleID === 1 ? "authenticated" : "public";
  // Find the ID of the public role
  const roleEntry = await strapi
    .query("plugin::users-permissions.role")
    .findOne({
      where: {
        type: roleName,
      },
    });

  // Create the new permissions and link them to the public role
  const allPermissionsToCreate = [];
  Object.keys(newPermissions).map((controller) => {
    const actions = newPermissions[controller];
    const permissionsToCreate = actions.map((action) => {
      return strapi.query("plugin::users-permissions.permission").create({
        data: {
          action: `api::${controller}.${controller}.${action}`,
          role: roleEntry.id,
        },
      });
    });
    allPermissionsToCreate.push(...permissionsToCreate);
  });
  await Promise.all(allPermissionsToCreate);
};
```

And then in my `beforeAll` block I call it like this:

```js
    await grantPrivilege(1, {
      "my-custom-collection": ["create", "update"],
      category: ["find", "findOne"],
      author: ["find", "findOne"],
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to grant the right privileges to your routes on your test DB.

For that you can create a function, lets call it grantPriviledge, and call it in your test in the function beforeAll.

```
// Here I want to grant the route update in my organization collection

beforeAll(async () => {
  await grantPrivilege(1, 'permissions.application.controllers.organization.update');
});
```

And here is the function grantPriviledge:

```
// roleID is 1 for authenticated and 2 for public

const grantPrivilege = async (roleID = 1, value, enabled = true, policy = '') => {
  const updateObj = value
    .split('.')
    .reduceRight((obj, next) => ({ [next]: obj }), { enabled, policy });

  const roleName = roleID === 1 ? 'Authenticated' : 'Public';
  const roleIdInDB = await strapi
    .query('role', 'users-permissions')
    .findOne({ name: roleName });
  return strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.userspermissions.updateRole(
    roleIdInDB,
    updateObj,
  );
};
```

Let me know if that helps